# Unity Dev for Gear VR - Equirectangular Panorama as skybox/sphere

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I've been trying to make a 360 photo viewer similar to the Oculus 360 Photos app. The only problem is when projecting onto a sphere with inverted normals, the image "warps" or "bends" as the sphere does, and results in straight lines such as door frames turning into bending images; bad result.

Changing the size of the sphere does nothing, and obviously the picture has to bend somewhere to fit onto the inner surface of the sphere, so I don't think this solution will work.

I then tried turning the photo into a cylindrical skybox, and using it as a skybox component of the camera, which works great: no bending lines, everything looks as desired. Except for one thing: there is a shimmering/aliasing effect on the texture, unless I enable mip maps, which then results in a blurred image.

Does anybody know how I could apply my image to appear similar to those in the Oculus 360 Photo app? They render with perfect quality and no bending lines, no shimmering. How do they achieve this result?

I've tried different compression types and different shapes, the only thing I haven't tried is slicing the photo into 6 pieces and rendering it on the inside of a cube around the camera, which, due to it's proximity, might not get the shimmery result that could be cause by distance from the camera?

Thoughts, suggestions, questions? Any assistance or discussion is appreciated

Comment: Try messing with different materials/shaders to fix the shimmering maybe. (edited because I can see from the title you are using a plain pano and not a 360 warped photo as the source - I think your best bet is the cylinder with the right material/shader/lighting)

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the issue with the sphere and the equirectangular file you want to use? Without them it's too much guessing.

Comment: Hi @chanibal, thank you for your response.

I was able to get good results by increasing the renderscale to 1.5 or higher, which eliminated the shimmery aliasing effect. Not 100% sure if this was an issue due to the Samsung s6 resolution, but I just work now with an enhanced render scale for higher quality regardless, and optimise elsewhere to save on framerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get good results by increasing the renderscale to 1.5 or higher, which eliminated the shimmery aliasing effect. Not 100% sure if this was an issue due to the Samsung s6 resolution, but I just work now with an enhanced render scale for higher quality regardless, and optimise elsewhere to save on framerate

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is old now but I had that problem too but on the oculus go and it is solved thanks to these instructions [here](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-to-develop-for-oculus-go/) & [here](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-build-android/)